# On Windows, copy a file to my network folders in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, file, copy

On windows, I have a file called "test.txt" in C:\Users\test\Documents and I would like to copy it on my network folder with a path (from properties) \10.2.2.22\my_folder\output

I correctly create the file on windows with this line:

```
File.open("#{Dir.pwd}/output.txt",'a') do |file|
   file.puts "Hello!"
end
```

Then, I tried to copy it

```
 sent_to_folder=exec('copy output.txt \\10.2.2.22\my_folder\output')
```

But I receive the error "The system cannot find the path specified".
If I run the same command through the cmd, the file is copied correctly

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` is the escape char, it must be escaped itself by an escape. So doubling all backslashes should work.

```
sent_to_folder=exec('copy output.txt \\\\10.2.2.22\\my_folder\\output')
```

You could alse use FileUtils [copy_file](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-copy_file) and use Unix style forward slashes; Ruby will convert them to Windows style. (I think; can't test)

Comment: How to implement the same in Linux machine ? Its making a copy in the same folder with named '\\\\10.2.2.22\\my_folder\\output' :(

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, you can just use forward slashes in your file path to remove the need to use messy escape characters. Ruby will convert them to backslash.

Use as follows:

```
require 'FileUtils'

FileUtils.cp('path/to/copy output.txt', '//10.2.2.22/my_folder/output')
```